# Как отправить почту ответом на письмо

Tags: php, smtp

Известен *id* письма.

Мне необходимо не просто отправить письмо на ящик, а чтобы это письмо было ответом на цепочку других писем.

Можно ли такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого в письмо-ответ надо добавить заголовок `In-Reply-To` с указанием значения заголовка `Message-Id` оригинального письма. В заголовок `References` ответа надо скопировать все ID из заголовка `References` оригинала и дописать после пробела значение заголовка `Message-Id` оригинального письма.

[RFC 2822, section 3.6.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4)

Answer (score 0):

Я не силен в php , но думаю вот этот вопрос будет полезен [message-id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371275/get-a-mail-application-to-recognize-a-reply-to-email-php)